# Zlib incorrect header check when decompressing

Tags: javascript, node.js, zlib

I need to receive a zip file from a server, extract it and pipe its contents elsewhere.

However when trying to extract it with `createInflate` from the zlib builtin package, I get the error `Error: incorrect header check`

(I have tried with `createUnzip` and `createGunzip` too)

Downloading the file with cUrl and extracting it with the `unzip` linux command works correctly.

```sh
$ unzip report.zip 
Archive:  report.zip
  inflating: report.csv
```

```
$ zipinfo -v report.zip
[...]
  file system or operating system of origin:      MS-DOS, OS/2 or NT FAT
  version of encoding software:                   2.0
  minimum file system compatibility required:     MS-DOS, OS/2 or NT FAT
  minimum software version required to extract:   2.0
  compression method:                             deflated
  compression sub-type (deflation):               normal
  file security status:                           not encrypted
  extended local header:                          yes
[...]
```

#### Code used to extract the already downloaded file:

```js
const pipeline = promisify(stream.pipeline);

(async () => {
  const unzipper = createInflate();
  const sourceStream = fs.createReadStream('report.zip');
  const destStream = fs.createWriteStream('report.csv');

  await pipeline(sourceStream, unzipper, destStream);
})();
```

Note that the error is the same between piping the response directly and piping the result of `createReadStream`

#### Full `zipinfo -v`:

```
$ zipinfo -v report.zip
Archive:  report.zip
There is no zipfile comment.

End-of-central-directory record:
-------------------------------

  Zip archive file size:                       527 (000000000000020Fh)
  Actual end-cent-dir record offset:           505 (00000000000001F9h)
  Expected end-cent-dir record offset:         505 (00000000000001F9h)
  (based on the length of the central directory and its expected offset)

  This zipfile constitutes the sole disk of a single-part archive; its
  central directory contains 1 entry.
  The central directory is 78 (000000000000004Eh) bytes long,
  and its (expected) offset in bytes from the beginning of the zipfile
  is 427 (00000000000001ABh).


Central directory entry #1:
---------------------------

  report_SMS_1f7c2069_20200730.csv

  offset of local header from start of archive:   0
                                                  (0000000000000000h) bytes
  file system or operating system of origin:      MS-DOS, OS/2 or NT FAT
  version of encoding software:                   2.0
  minimum file system compatibility required:     MS-DOS, OS/2 or NT FAT
  minimum software version required to extract:   2.0
  compression method:                             deflated
  compression sub-type (deflation):               normal
  file security status:                           not encrypted
  extended local header:                          yes
  file last modified on (DOS date/time):          2020 Jul 30 11:05:48
  32-bit CRC value (hex):                         5abe6238
  compressed size:                                349 bytes
  uncompressed size:                              934 bytes
  length of filename:                             32 characters
  length of extra field:                          0 bytes
  length of file comment:                         0 characters
  disk number on which file begins:               disk 1
  apparent file type:                             binary
  non-MSDOS external file attributes:             000000 hex
  MS-DOS file attributes (00 hex):                none

  There is no file comment.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zlib is not zip. zip is not zlib. They are two different formats. gzip is yet another. (The use of the word "unzip" in the node.js zlib interface is misleading.)

You need something that unzips zip files. Take a look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzip).

Comment: The compression method is deflated so you'd think an inflate decompress would work.

Comment: Would zlib and zip be considered serializations of compression/decompression?

Comment: Inflate decompress _does_ work, if you decode the zip format to hunt down and locate the deflate-compressed data therein for each entry. That assumes the zip file is using the deflate compression method, out of more than a dozen possibilities. However 99.9% of the zip files out there use either the deflate or stored compression methods (stored is no compression).

Comment: zlib, zip, gzip, tar.gz, etc. are _wrappers_ around compressed data, where the wrappers provide metadata and integrity checks of the contents.